# How to get the binary code of part of the source code while compiling with LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, code-generation

For example, I have a C++ file called test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  int a = 0;
  int b = 1;
  char c = '3';
  cout<< a <<endl;  //  We want to get the binary code from here
  cout<< b <<endl;  //  to here
  cout<< c <<endl;
}
```

When I compile it with LLVM (I guess LLVM should be modified), how can I get the binary code as the comments say above?

Do I need to insert extra flags to distinguish them from others?

Comment: www.godbolt.org

Comment: I am wondering if I can get the binary code using LLVM instead of using existing tools.

Comment: Why do you need this? If we understand the problem you are trying to solve we can give more pertinent answers

Comment: The problem is we want to hash the value of that binary code during compiling stage

Comment: What do you mean by "binary code"? The native binary (e.g an object file), LLVM bitcode, something else? Also, wouldn't hashing on the IR level help somehow?

Answer (score 0):

First add `using namespace std;` so that your code compiles and after that try 
 `g++ -S <your file here> -o result`. Now open the result file.